# Understanding GraphQL Union types

Tags: graphql

While experimenting with the Union types in GraphQL here: https://graphql.github.io/learn/schema/#union-types I ran into the following:

[image]

I initially thought that the fields you specify in the query are the fields that going to be searched for the text: "Millenium", however that's not the case because I'm still getting the Millenium Falcon's data even after removing the name field from the query for the `Startship` type.

I did another test: R2-D2's `primaryFunction` is `Astromech`, if you search for `Astromech` you'll get nothing, even if `primaryFunction` is specified for `Droid` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that name is still specified on Starship because otherwise it wouldn't show up in the results given that Starship is not a Character!

That simply means that because we are using a Union type, given two types that are part of the Union that both have a `name` field, you still have to request the `name` field for each type in their inline fragment. Omitting the `name` for the `Starship` fragment, but including it on `Character`, means if the returned type is a `Character` the name field will be present but it will not be present on the `Starship` type.

The docs are mentioning this to highlight the difference between Unions and Interfaces. **If** SearchResult was an Interface that included the `name` field and `Character` and `Starship` implemented that Interface, you could do something like this instead:

```
{
  search(text: "an") {
    name
    __typename
    ... on Human {
      height
    }
    ... on Droid {
      primaryFunction
    }
    ... on Starship {
      length
    }
  }
}
```

But because Unions don't guarantee any fields are shared between their types, it's not possible to do so with Unions.

With regards to search, that's not something that's baked into GraphQL. This particular schema happens to have a `search` field on its `Query` type and that field resolves a particular way. If you were creating a server, you could write a search field that considered the requested fields as part of the search criteria. But this is an implementation detail and not related to how GraphQL works in general.